# Is it Possible to make FK reference with mysql.user?

Tags: mysql, mysql-workbench

is it possible to make a FK referencing the mysql.user?

Im using MySQL Workbench 8.0, and when i try to select this table to make the reference, i can't "see" mysql.user there

To overcome that, i used the option Specify Manually and typed "mysql.user"

By doing that, i could find mysql.user table, however, when i try to select a referenced column, MySQL Workbench doesn't allow me to, it always stay blank despite i select the colunm i want to refer, also im trying to do this as admin

Comment: you need to look though the Foreign key documentation, and also bear in mind that the user needs read access to the mysql.user table, which is probably not wise. besides that, foreign keys only have real effect on innodb tables, and afaik, the mysql.user table is MyISAM

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could do a "weak foreign key", a column with the same type but without create the relationship of foreign key.

Comment: Well, so i think that means no, i can't do what i want hehe. Looks like i'll have to go the other method i was wondering about before, but thanks. I'll not mark best answer yet, just in case anyone else has another response